# Use custom cursor over an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, cursor

I am using the following code to change the cursor when clicking on a button:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
       $("*").css("cursor", "url('images/cur_circle_01.png'), auto");
   });
```

The cursor changes as expected, but as soon as I move the mouse over the iframe, the cursor reverts to normal.

Is there a way to fix this? The intended behavior is to change the mouse pointer based on button clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but deserves an answer. I use a div as an overlay and instead of adding cursor to the elements I just have it on the div. This way the iframe has the appearance of having a cursor over it. The important thing is to toggle it off once loading is complete otherwise you won't be able to click on anything. (Adjust size and position to fit over iframe window).

```
<style>
    #overlay{
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:10000;
        cursor: wait !important;
    }
</style>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<iframe id="myiframe" sr=""></iframe>
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Click Me" />

<script>
    //Show overlay, load iframe src
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        $('#overlay').show();
        $('#myiframe').attr('src','https://www.google.com');
    });

    //Hide overlay after load of iframe.
    $('#myiframe').load(function () {
        $('#overlay').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Google won't load in an Iframe on JSFiddle but this gives you a working idea. https://jsfiddle.net/tbkyjwLn/2/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the cursor when it is over an `<iframe>`. This is because the browser is rendering a completely different web page, with it's own HTML and JS executing within your main HTML document.